# percent encode out of range exception

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, urlencode, utf-16

I have a problem with percent.encode() in `package:convert/convert.dart` package.
I have an API that is used by the Arabs and can contain Arabic characters. One of the Arabic characters is `"خ"` and if I want to convert it with this method `percent.encode('خ'.codeUnits)`. The code unit number is 1582 which represents `0x62e` in hexadecimal. In this case, I will get an exception because it's out of range of the bytes that this library can convert. and I have this exception `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid byte 0x62`. Can you please help me with my problem? are there any alternatives I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, I've used `Uri.encodeQueryComponent(data)`. It did the trick.

[Update 1]

There is an alternative way

```dart
percent.encode(utf8.encode('خ'))
```